# How to run two cases with different functions at the same time?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I know that it is possible to run multi cases if all do the same action. Considering the example below, if it is true that A and B, then do something...

```
switch(true){
 case A:
 case B:
  //do something;
 break;
 case C:
  //do something else;}
```

However, I am not sure how to make it work for the following:

```
switch(true){
 case A:
  alert("A");
 case B:
  alert("B");
 break;
 case C:
  //do something else;}
```

If it is true that both A and B, it should alert "A" and "B". Probably, switch statement is not a good option for the example, but I could not figure this out. Any suggestion, recommendation?

Comment: What exactly is the question? This doesn't make sense as posted.

Comment: This is unclear - how could it be two different cases at the same time?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth looks like `&&` condition where as first case is `||` :)

Comment: Switch statement is the wrong choice for that logic.

Comment: To make it clear: Let's assume you are given apple, orange and banana. If apple is green, eat it; if not, throw it away. If orange is sweet, give it to your mom; if not, throw it away. If banana is fresh, keep it; if not, put into trash. Consequently, the apple is green and orange is sweet, but banana is rotten. So you will eat apple and give the orange to your mom. Two out of three cases are true and each case asks you to do something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to use the `switch` incorrectly, it looks like you're trying to check if `A`, `B` and `C` are true and if they are run the matching `alert()`.
The purpose of a `switch` is to check what the value being given is (so only one case can be true) and run it, like so:

```
function demoFunction1(fruit){
    var sentence = "";
    switch (fruit) {
        case "apple": sentence = "I love apples!"; break;
        case "banana": sentence = "I hate bananas!"; break;
        case "watermelon": sentence = "Watermelon is okay"; break;
    }
    alert(sentence);
}
```

So this is checking what the value of `fruit` is, if it's `"apple"`, `"banana"` or `"watermelon"` it will run the matching case's code.

It looks to me like what you wanna use is if statements like so:

```
function demoFunction2(A, B, C){
    if (A) { 
        alert("A");
    }
    if (B) {
        alert("B");
    }
    if (C) {
        alert("C");
    }
}
```

This way you're checking if `A`, `B` and `C` are `true` individually and if any of them are then what's in the `{}` of the if statement will run (such as function calls or in this case alerts). This will work for any combination of `A`, `B` and `C` being `true`/`false`.

Answer (score 0):

So you got confused with explaining your problem.

```
 case A:
 case B:
  //do something;
```

This is an or condition, if it is A or if it is B, it gets true and execute.

What you are looking for

> If it is true that both A and B, it should alert "A" and "B".

In that case switch won't work. Go back to tradational `else if`

```
if (str.equals("A") && str.equals("B")) {

  alert("A");
  alert("B");

}else if( str.equals("C")){

 alert("C");

}else...... // other conditions
```

Answer (score 0):

You should basically never use `switch(true)` (unless you need a lot of fall-through), using `if`/`else` is much cleaner. In your case, you would have

```
if (A || B) {
  // do something;
} else if (C) {
  // do something else;
}
```

and could trivially change this to

```
if (A && B) {
  alert("A");
  alert("B");
} else if (C) {
  // do something else;
}
```

when that suits your new requirements. (Yes, you could also have done `case A && B:` but that's much harder to understand)